# Eclipse Marketplace Install pending

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace, editbox

I just installed a new version of eclipse IDE(2020-12) and tried to install the plugins I had on the older version but had no success.
As shown in the picture, when I find the plugin in the Eclipse marketplace and click install, "install pending" shows up and nothing happens. I neither get any pop-ups that ask me to proceed with the installation nor see any progress at the bottom right of the eclipse window. For the older version(2019-06), I can install without any changes in preferences or some other sort of settings. I wonder what could cause this issue?
[image: Install pending]

Comment: One way to start investigation is to take a Java threads dump. It might point some thread blocked and give an idea.
Also, have you checked the error log?

Comment: BTW, I am using eclipse for C/C++, but I have all the java development software installed, and I also have a JDK included. Not sure if it's because of the fact the Eclipse for C doesn't recognize jar (EditBox is a jar I think)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but it works via update site: http://editbox.sourceforge.net/updates

From Eclipse menu open: Help->Install New Software and paste the link.

I think the problem is with Editbox but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong (I'm the author of the plugin).